# Convert variable as Timestamp in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I know similar question has been asked multiple times before but I have tried all those options and still not get desired result.

I have a sdf as kl in following format:

```
   CONSUMER_ID   TimeStamp        TimeStamp2        
          <dbl>    <dbl>                <chr>              
 1       958    20171201000002 20171201000002        
 2       985    20171201000005 20171201000005
```

I want to convert Timestamp in format "yyyy/MM/dd H:M:S"

I have tried multiple options which I found online but nothing works for this format.

Ex:

```
library(sparklyr)             
library(dplyr)

ms_rech_10 = kl %>% mutate(time_2 = date(timestamp(unix_timestamp(TimeStamp2))))

ms_rech_12 = kl %>% mutate(time_2 = date(TimeStamp2))

ms_rech_12 = kl %>% mutate(time_2 = to_date(TimeStamp2))
```

But in each code I got following output:

```
  CONSUMER_ID      TimeStamp     TimeStamp2     time_2    
          <dbl>          <dbl>       <chr>       <date>    
 1        958     20171201000002 20171201000002   NA        
 2        985     20171201000005 20171201000005   NA
```

Please provide the solution in following format.

```
    CONSUMER_ID      TimeStamp     TimeStamp2     time_2    
          <dbl>          <dbl>       <chr>       <dttm>    
 1        958     20171201000002 20171201000002   2017/12/01 00:00:02        
 2        985     20171201000005 20171201000005   2017/12/01 00:00:05
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need formatted string (**you cannot have** formatted timestamp):

```
df <- copy_to(sc, tibble(Timestamp2=c("20171201000002", "20171201000005")))

df %>%  
  mutate(time2 = from_unixtime(
    unix_timestamp(Timestamp2, "yyyyMMddHHmmss"), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))

# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
  Timestamp2     time2              
  <chr>          <chr>              
1 20171201000002 2017/12/01 00:00:02
2 20171201000005 2017/12/01 00:00:05
```

otherwise just use `to_timestamp(Timestamp2, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

Comment: Thanks for code : to_timestamp gives error:                                                                         Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'TO_TIMESTAMP'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 62

Comment: Sounds like you use outdated Spark version.

Comment: Spark version is 2.1.0

Comment: So any other alternative for 2.1.0 version for to_timestamp

Comment: Use the first approach to convert to iso format, and then call convert to timestamp?